# Applying OOP to refactor my Windows Forms APP

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, winforms

Could you please give me some direction about how I could refactor my code? As I add functionalities to my Budget App the class is getting bigger and I'm sure I could start looking at separating concerns and maybe using some sort of abstraction.

I've been studying OOP for a few months now but I'm not sure how to apply this knowledge to the controls on a windows form app. All I could come up with so far is to separate the calculations I  want to make with the budget entries, which I'll do next.

Here's the link to my form code:

https://github.com/pablo-the-souza/Budget1.1/blob/master/Budget1.1/Form1.cs

And here's a snippet:

```
 private void fillByDateAndCategoryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mainTableAdapter1.FillByDateAndCategory
               (
               this.dataSet2.main,
               categoryCB.SelectedItem.ToString(),
               monthCalendarStart.SelectionRange.Start.ToString(), monthCalendarStart.SelectionRange.End.ToString()
               );
        }

        private void FillByDateAndTypeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mainTableAdapter1.FillByDateAndType
               (
               this.dataSet2.main,
               typeCB.SelectedItem.ToString(),
               monthCalendarStart.SelectionRange.Start.ToString(), monthCalendarStart.SelectionRange.End.ToString()
               );
        }
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We require that **the code be embedded directly**. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).